Logging in Firefox ESR
I am trying to get Firefox-ESR to log HTTP connections.
Per:
https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/networking/http/logging.html
I should be able to do that by:
export MOZ_LOG=timestamp,rotate:200,nsHttp:5,cache2:5,nsSocketTransport:5,nsHostResolver:5
export MOZ_LOG_FILE=/tmp/log.txt

(or launching with these options).
However none of these seem to work.
Any ideas on how to force Firefox-ESR to log its activity?
